# IE + Selenium : Is there any way to disable pop-up blocker programmatically in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Each time I move into new IE browser to run Selenium automation scripts which deals with pop-up handling, I need to disable pop-up blocker option from IE settings manually. Is there a way to disable IE pop-up blocker programmatically by using some capability or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to modify Registry value to be able to manipulate pop-up blocker in IE. Registry information is given below:

**Registry Location:** *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows*

**Registry Value Name:** *PopupMgr*

**Registry Value Data:** *no [Turn off pop-up blocker]* and *yes [Turn on pop-up blocker]*

If you are with Java and want to achieve it programmatically, following code snippet will surely help you:

```
String cmd = "REG ADD \"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\New Windows\" /F /V \"PopupMgr\" /T REG_SZ /D \"no\"";
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error ocured!");
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use like this in Ruby binding WebDriver:

```
 caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer('ie.unexpectedAlertBehaviour' => 'accept', 'ignoreProtectedModeSettings' => true)
 @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:ie, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Let me know if that works for you! otherwise change `'ie.unexpectedAlertBehaviour' => 'dismiss'` either one should be works

Comment: Thanks @mcbuddy for replying. Unfortunately, setting 'ie.unexpectedAlertBehaviour' didn't work for me. By further investigating I found out that this is to auto handle unexpected alerts which is not my intention here. Rather I want to turn-off pop-up blocker programmatically. Finally I could achieve it by setting Registry value. Please follow my answer posted below.