# How to disable popups in ie11 while downloading .pdf files?

Tags: selenium, popup, internet-explorer-11

[image]

I am trying to download a pdf file in ie11. How do I disable this popup?

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012076/ie-selenium-is-there-any-way-to-disable-pop-up-blocker-programmatically-in-i

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I tried but still I am getting the same download popup

Comment: I try to find the option for disabling the open/save popup for specific files in IE 11 but looks like this option got removed in IE 11. I got many links and documentation for this option but all are for older version and the solution is not compatible with IE 11.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT exactly what i am facing right now!

Comment: can you please inform us, which OS you are using currently? If you are using Windows 10 OS and you are available to switch to MS Edge than it can help you to work around this issue. Let me know, whether you are available with this option or not. I will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I am working on Windows10 but I have to automate scenarios in IE11 only. It is a requirement.

Comment: This change was done in IE 11 for security purpose, So it will not be available in IE anymore. If you are trying to automate something using IE than I suggest to check for selenium, whether it provides any work around.

Answer (score 0):

Open My Computer > Tools > Folder Options > File Types > PDF > Advanced :
Clear the 'Confirm open after download'

[image: ScreenshotToDisablePop-up]

Kindly upvote and confirm if it works for you.

Comment: When i opened folder options i donot get FileTypes tab under it. I am only able to view General, View and Search Tabs